# Kendo DropDownList with Nested Object as TextField

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a kendo-dropdownlist and want to assign the textField property to an attribute that lies within a nested object.

User Object:

```
{ 
  id: 123456  <--valueField
  contact: {
      name: Jane Doe <--textField
      email: 
      ...
  }
}
```

**The issue is Kendo does not display the name in the selected box nor the dropdown because it cannot seem to find the contact.name attribute or any other attribute within the contact object.**

Here is how I have it configured and would assume for it to be since the grid's *kendo-grid-column* `field` property can use nested object attribute names:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist id="profileOwner"
                    [data]="userData"
                    [textField]="'contact.name'"
                    [valueField]="'id'"
                    [(ngModel)]="profileOwner"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

I know Kendo can find the object because when I set the the text field to `[textField]="'contact'"` it results with showing the following:
[Object,Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpDi9.png)

I have tried the various configurations:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist id="profileOwner"
                    [data]="userData"
                    [textField]="contact.name"  <-- Cannot find object error 
                    [valueField]="'id'"
                    [(ngModel)]="profileOwner"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
---
<kendo-dropdownlist id="profileOwner"
                    [data]="userData"
                    textField="contact.name"  <-- I still get Nothing
                    valueField="id"
                    [(ngModel)]="profileOwner"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

My intended workaround before making this post was to use the item template to show the values. This successfully shows the values in the dropdown window but not in the selected box:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist id="profileOwner"
                    [data]="userData"
                    [textField]="'contact.name'"
                    [valueField]="'id'"
                    [(ngModel)]="profileOwner"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true">
         <ng-template kendoDropDownListItemTemplate let-dataItem>
                <span class="template">{{ dataItem.contact.name }}</span>
         </ng-template>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

[Workaround attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne1Q2.png)

Version Info:

```
Angular: 7.2.9
@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns: ^3.5.0
```

Comment: have you tried using method instead on object value ?

Comment: have you tried using code like this ?  **[textField]="getText(contact)"** and then in your method **getText(obj){return obj.name}**

Comment: I have not, let me give that a shot.

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil That didn't work. Since the textField does not emit an event, the function will not know for what user to return the name. 
And unfortunately, textField does not accept an array of inputs. It is the field name that Kendo of the object kendo is asking for.

From their documentation: 
 /**  Sets the data item field that represents the item value. */
    valueField: string;

Answer (score -1):

Simple. Just change your code as below:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist id="profileOwner"
                    [data]="userData"
                    [textField]="contact.name"
                    [valueField]="id"
                    [(ngModel)]="profileOwner"
                    [valuePrimitive]="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

this because why you sould bind for example the id line `[valueField]="id"` not an string `[valueField]="'id'"`.

Comment: This does not address the question. The value field is not what the issue is referring to. Nonetheless, kendo is expecting the string value of the attribute to look for in the textField or valueField inputs.